# Drupal 7 - Menu items display depending on roles and views

Tags: menu, module, drupal-7, roles

I'm working on a Drupal project that requires few tiered user roles. High level users will have certain admin roles, but there will also be two lower level roles- a sales person and a standard customer. Sales person role will need to be able to create standard customers and then view data related to any customer they created.

Since I'm using profile2, the typical user account task menu looks like this

http://oi57.tinypic.com/333v447.jpg

Now, when a logged in user is sales person role and they go to 'my account' they are not supposed to see My Subscriptions, Orders or Invoices. Vendor details profile2 link should be also disabled. But since they can view data of customers they added to the system, those links have to appear if they view other user screen

In terms of code, I played with the following idea for starters

```
function mymodules_menu_alter(&$menu) {
  global $user;

  $viewed_user_id = null;
  $uid = arg(1);
  if ( arg(0) == 'user' && is_numeric($uid) ) {
    $viewed_user_id = $uid;
  }

  if (in_array('sales executive', $user->roles) && $viewed_user_id == $user->uid ) {    
    unset($menu['user/%user_category/edit/vendor_details']);
  }

  if (in_array('sales executive', $user->roles) ) {    
    unset($menu['user/%user/user-recurring-entities']);
  }
}
```

Problem is, that first check for vendor_details behaves weird. It either displays the menu for all roles, or for none. I'm thinking caching may be affecting this?

The second check doesn't work at all as such menu entry doesn't exist in $menu array.

So my basic question is, how to make the whole thing work? Perhaps my approach is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely an interesting approach.

Drupal menu has permission check build in, in theory, if you don't have permission to access certain page, the menu link won't appear. This is the default behavior.

Ex. let's take "Orders" as example, if Order page is build using views, you can edit views, and set the views permission to target certain role or Drupal permissions.

Of course, you might use variety of ways to assemble your page, ex. views is one, panels is another, or just plain hook_menu. But more or less you should play with the permission access instead of menu directly. And sometimes you need to write your own version of permission, which is what you did in your code.